# Sympy plot piecewise TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, sympy, piecewise

I'm trying to figure out how to plot the following sympy piecewise function

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy.plotting import plot
```

...

```
def camber_line(self):
    """The equation of the camber line"""
    m = self._max_camber
    p = self._max_camber_pos
    c = float(self._chord.value)
    """"Symmetrical airfoils"""
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    """Cambered airfoils"""
    return sympy.Piecewise(
        (c * m / p**2 * (2 * p * (x / c) - (x / c)**2), x <= p * c),
        (c * m / (1 - p)**2 * ((1 - 2 * p) + 2 * p * (x / c) - (x / c)**2), x >= p * c)
    )
```

somewhere else

```
plot(self.camber_line(), (x, 0, self._chord))
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py", line 194, in __call__
    result = complex(self.lambda_func(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py", line 316, in __call__
    return self.lambda_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aero464ass4.py", line 66, in _calc_button_action
    plot(self.camber_line(), (x, 0, self._chord))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1295, in plot
    plots.show()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 196, in show
    self._backend.show()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1029, in show
    self.process_series()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 908, in process_series
    collection = self.LineCollection(s.get_segments())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 514, in get_segments
    f_start = f(self.start)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py", line 231, in __call__
    result = self.lambda_func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py", line 316, in __call__
    return self.lambda_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'
```

There is something wrong with the inequality comparison. The sympy symbol seems to be a complex number? Anyone have a suggestion how I can get this to work? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
turning off adaptive sampling fixes it but also gives a cryptic error

```
plot(self.camber_line(), (x, 0, self._chord), adaptive=False, nb_of_points=400)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py:165: UserWarning: The evaluation of the expression is problematic. We are trying a failback method that may still work. Please report this as a bug.
  warnings.warn('The evaluation of the expression is'
```

Comment: A [mcve], including the values of m, p, c, self._chord, would help.

Comment: one of the values in the inequality probably has a small imaginary part. You might try defining `pc = re(p*c)` and then use condiions like `re(x) <= pc` in the Piecewise...assuming you are plotting this in the real plane and that `p` and `c` are real.